# Chrome ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: google-chrome, curl

I have a problem with chrome which don't display some of my static files (css, js mainly). it says that an empty response has been sent by the server

[image]

but when I try to "curl" the same URL, it works

[image]

I don't really know what's wrong here. I tried disabling cache, clearing all type of cache, incognito mode, disabling chrome extensions... none of those worked
thanks

## update

If I try to access the same URL with a random parameter in query string (let's say ?id=1), it works but only once ! when I refresh the page, I get the same error, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem : 
I had something wrong in my `.htaccess` file. I had `module_deflate` which wasn't enabled in my apache configuration, so somehow, this prevented my local website to work properly. Just enabled it in my `/etc/apache/http.conf` and that's it.

If you get the same problem, I would recommend to comment all your `.htaccess` lines and then uncomment them one by one to see if any of them can cause the problem.
hope this would help someone else.